# SharePoint:ScriptLink to the root web?

Tags: 2010

I have the following code, but I am very sure it will only work in the homepage of our website, and not when having the following scenario

```
-root
    -web1
      -web2





<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="/js/SP.Ribbon.js" LoadAfterUI="true" OnDemand="false" runat="server" Localizable="false"/>

  ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(initCOBRibbon, '/js/SP.Ribbon.js');
```

Is there anyspecific way to put in the name attribut that it should be the layouts in the root?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ScriptLink is automatically linked to layouts folder in the hive (14-folder). So the name="/xxx/js/SP.Ribbon.js" goes to 
`/web1/web2/_layouts/xxx/js/SP.Ribbon.js` which is actually the same file as if it would be `<root>/_layouts/xxx/js/SP.Ribbon.js`

Comment: the last line in my example, Do I need to put the same path, or just the name of the file?

Comment: the name refers to the file path seen from 14\Layouts. So if your file is in 14\Layouts\my-awesome.js, the name is "my-awesome.js" If your script is inside a subfolder(s), add them into name with slash (not backslash): 14\Layouts\xxx\js\SP.Ribbon.js -> `name="xxx/js/SP.Ribbon.js"`